# Mpiexec taking forever to start (possible issue with MPIPoolExecutor)?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpi4py, mpich, mpiexec

I am trying to run the following command:

`mpiexec -n 1 python scratch.py`

where scratch.py is a simple example provided [here](https://groups.google.com/g/mpi4py/c/k7Hc6raaWgY)

```
from mpi4py.futures import MPIPoolExecutor
def square(i):
global initialized
try:
    initialized
except NameError:
    initialized = False
if not initialized:
    print("expensive initialization")
import time
time.sleep(2)
initialized = True
return i**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MPIPoolExecutor(2) as ex:
        for result in ex.map(square, range(7)):
            print (result)
```

Which lingers on indefinitely

ps aux | grep mpi gives:

`username 16944 44.6  0.0 377280 14476 ?        Rl   09:46   0:03 python -R -m mpi4py.futures.server`

So, I understand that problem lies within MPIPoolExecutor. I also wondered if there was a firewall constraint but, systemctl status firewalld gives

`firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: inactive (dead) Docs: man:firewalld(1)` 
What exactly does "python -R -m mpi4py.futures.server" do and why does it take forever?

I have;

- Python3 version 3.8.0
- mpich version 4.2.0

Using Scientific Linux 7.4

CPU details:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               3300.000
CPU max MHz:           3500.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              6000.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Finally, running the command python3 -R -m mpi4py.futures.server individually yields the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/server.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/server.py", line 10, in main
    _lib.server_main()
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py", line 1068, in server_main
    server_main_service()
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py", line 1057, in server_main_service
    comm = server_accept(service, info)
  File "/home/people/hkaya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py", line 1006, in server_accept
    MPI.Publish_name(service, port, info)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 2755, in mpi4py.MPI.Publish_name
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
  Proc: [[32891,0],0]
  Errorcode: 1
```

Comment: To avoid issues with you code, could you provide a minimal example that fails to start. It seems like you execute one program which spawns additional processes, maybe just let them spawn and print something.
Second, could you provide some info about your computing environment. Like what machine(s) you are running on and how they are connected.
MPICH 3.0.3 is also crazy old, that is probably not the issue here, but working with newer versions avoids all kinds of problems

Comment: Dear @Niklas, ok I updated the question. even when running a very simple example with MPIPoolExecutor, I am still having the same issue.

Comment: The scratch program you provided worked (after proper formatting) for me without issues. 
mpi4py version 3.1.5
OpenMPI version 4.0.5
python 3.8.10
`mpiexec -n  1 python3 test.py`.
You can also add `from mpi4py import MPI` as first line and add `print("Rank: ", MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank())` in the `square` function to see that multiple processes are spawned.
I would recommend updating your software, especially the old MPICH library and confirm that it works properly.

Comment: Dear @Niklas, I have followed your suggestions and updated my mpich library to 4.2.0, but I am still not getting any printout or job completion. In addition to the mpi4py.futures.server command, another output from ps aux is: 

username+ 19815  0.0  0.0  10376   724 ?        Ss   14:20   0:00 ~/mpich-install/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy --control-port workstation3.cem-uct.ac.za:45726 --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --usize -2 --pmi-port 0 --gpus-per-proc -2 --gpu-subdevs-per-proc -2 --proxy-id 0

Comment: The error message `MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank..." strongly suggests `mpi4py` is using Open MPI. You should first double check that and use`mpiexec` that matches the MPI library used by `mpi4py`

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions commented under my question, I double checked and found that mpi4py was indeed using a different library from what mpiexec was linked to. So, I uninstalled and reinstalled mpi4py with mpich libraries [using this link](https://pypi.org/project/mpi4py-mpich/), now MPIPoolExecutor runs without any issues. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This probably should have ideally been a comment, but it’s okay.